# Laravel root directory not public on Hostinger hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

I currently host my Laravel website on Hostinger, but when I have a image on my page, the url doesn't go to website.com/public/img_url, but it goes to website.com/img_url, does anyone know how this works on Hostinger, and how I can fix this?

Currently my whole project is in my public_html, with no other folders besides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution was changing my htaccess to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to add a public inside asset function to access a public folder on the shared hosting server.

So you need to change the fetch path of files Example: `asset('user/photo.jpg')` to `asset('public/user/photo.jpg')` in each line of code where you need to fetch files from the public directory.

Comment: Yeah, but then it doesn't work locally anymore haha. Is there any way to get it working right on Hostinger and on my local environment?

Comment: This path also run on local server on pc. You need to run via calling url like : http://localhost/project_folder_name/public